# Bochner integral definition, I don't understand why this is true?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I have read something and I don'tunderstand why it is true!!

> Let $f \in L^2(0,t_0;X)$ where $X=L^2(\Omega)$ is Banach. By definition of the Bochner integral, there exists a seequince of measurable step functions 
>   $$f_n(x,t) = \sum_{j=1}^n f_{j,n}(x)\mathbf{1}_{T_i}(t)$$
>   converging pointwise a.e. to $f$ in $X$. Here, $f_{j,n} \in X$ and $T_i$ partitions $[0,t_0]$.

So they say that 
$$\lVert f_n(t) - f(t) \rVert_{X} \to 0$$?
But I thought that it is only true that
$$\lVert f_n - f \rVert_{L^2(0,t_0;X)} \to 0?$$

What is the matter with my thinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit $\|f_n(t) - f(t)\|_X \rightarrow 0$ holds for almost every $t$; this is precisely what it means for $f_n$ to converge pointwise a.e. to $f$ in $X$. So it is true merely by assumption. Without any additional context, all I can speculate is that your book is then going to show that $\|f_n - f\|_{L^2(0,t_0; X)} \rightarrow 0$, which is stronger than the statement above.

The whole process is analogous to how we originally define the Lebesgue integral; we take an approximation by step functions, define the integral on those, and then take the limiting value of the integral to be the Lebesgue integral on the original function.

Comment: Thanks. The issue is that we only know that $\lVert f_n - f\rVert_{L^2(0,t_0;X)} \to 0$ by definition of Bochner integral. The author say that it holds that $\lVert f_n(t) - f(t) \rVert_X \to 0$ -- I don't understand why that is true or how it follows..

Comment: Oh, I see the context now. In that case, what they're claiming is analogous to the result in regular $L^p$ space theory: if $f_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^p$, then there is a subsequence $f_{n_k} \rightarrow g$ pointwise a.e.